# Raphael.js two different animations, one hover

Tags: javascript, raphael

I'm drawing up an interactive map in RaphaelJS and have it working pretty good, but I'm stuck currently. Each region of the map has a label and on hover, the path needs to fill in and the label needs to change color.

I've got the animation triggering to fill the region, I can also animate the text in the same function, however, when you mouseover the text it treats it as a mouseout on the region. So I need them to be animating together.

I've trying using set's but i'm not exactly sure how it should all work, my attempts so far have been unsuccessful. Here is some code,

My Paths and text are all repeated like this:

```
var text_1808 = rsr.set();
text_1808.push(rsr.text(0, 0, '1808'));
text_1808.attr({
  fill: '#0A4E74',
  "font-family": 'source-sans-pro',
  "font-size": '14.9932',
  'stroke-width': '0',
  'stroke-opacity': '1',
  parent: 'text_1808'
});
text_1808.transform("m0.9587 0 0 1 194.3486 207.7305").data('id', 'text_1808');

var path_1808 = rsr.set();
path_1808.push(rsr.path("M 204.229,244.362 204.229,227.229   182.418,227.229 182.418,170.131 196.231,170.131 196.231,159.05 190.202,159.05 190.202,146.476 223.082,146.476 223.082,153.354   222.255,153.354 222.255,175.604 246.281,175.604 246.281,244.362  z"));
path_1808.attr({
  fill: '#ffffff',
  stroke: '#0A4E74',
  parent: 'suite_1808',
  "stroke-linecap": 'round',
  "stroke-linejoin": 'round',
  'stroke-width': '1',
  'stroke-opacity': '1'
}).data('id', 'path_1808');
```

Then I call the animations like so

```
var suites = [path_q, path_r, path_s, path_t, path_u, path_1808, path_w];
var labels = [text_1808, text_ac, text_ad, text_ae, text_af, text_ag, text_ah];

for (i = 0; i <= suites.length; i++) {
el = suites[i];

if(el !== undefined){

    el.mouseover(function() {
         this.animate({ cursor: 'pointer', fill: '#0A4E74' }, 200); 
     });

    el.mouseout(function() { 
         this.animate({ fill: '#ffffff' }, 200); 
     });

    el.click(function() { 
         this.animate({ fill: '#EC008C' }, 200); 
     });

}
```

}

so this code works in that it fill's the region properly, but then triggers the mouse out when you mouse over the text. Any and all suggestions appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Sets are sometimes a bit fiddly with events I find. You could set an id from one to the other which is then used and you set two animations together (this may depend a bit on how complex the final solution is). I would also call a set a set in the description rather than text, as its a bit more confusing otherwise. Here is an example that could work....fiddle is here http://jsfiddle.net/baYWR/2/

```
var text_1808 = rsr.text(50, 50, '1808');
text_1808.id = 'text_1808';
var set_1808 = rsr.set();  ///use one set for the lot, could be handy for manipulation later, rather than one set for each object, unless you will add to those.

text_1808.attr({
  'fill': '#0A4E74',
  "font-family": 'source-sans-pro',
  "font-size": '14.9932',
  'stroke-width': '0',
  'stroke-opacity': '1',
  parent: 'text_1808' 
});
text_1808.transform("m0.9587 0 0 1 194.3486 207.7305");

set_1808.push( text_1808 );


var path_1808 = rsr.path("M 204.229,244.362 204.229,227.229   182.418,227.229    182.418,170.131 196.231,170.131 196.231,159.05 190.202,159.05 190.202,146.476 223.082,146.476 223.082,153.354   222.255,153.354 222.255,175.604 246.281,175.604 246.281,244.362  z");
path_1808.id = 'path_1808';
path_1808.attr({
  fill: '#ffffff',
  stroke: '#0A4E74',
  parent: 'suite_1808',
  "stroke-linecap": 'round',
  "stroke-linejoin": 'round',
  'stroke-width': '1',
  'stroke-opacity': '1'
}).data( 'textid', 'text_1808' );
set_1808.push ( path_1808 );

var suites = [path_1808];
//var labels = [text_1808];

for (i = 0; i <= suites.length; i++) {
    el = suites[i];

    if(el !== undefined){

        el.mouseover(function() {
           this.animate({ cursor: 'pointer', fill: '#0A4E74' }, 200); 
           rsr.getById( this.data('textid') ).animate({ fill: '#0A4E74' }, 20);
        });

        el.mouseout(function() { 
            this.animate({ fill: '#ffffff' }, 200); 
            rsr.getById( this.data('textid') ).animate({ fill: '#0A4E74' }, 20);
        });

        el.click(function() { 
             this.animate({ fill: '#EC008C' }, 200); 
             rsr.getById( this.data('textid') ).animate({ fill: '#EC008C' }, 20);
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: ahhh ok! Thanks man. It seems easy now but I had a hard time see'ing it like this. I will update my code when i'm finished as I plan to abstract it as much as possible. Thanks!